# Is it possible to remove a file from history using interactive git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

There's an old commit in my local repository which added some files, including one called "unwanted.txt". In subsequent commits, that file has been modified, along with others. Is it possible to completely remove the file "unwanted.txt" from history using interactive git rebase?
I know it's possible to achieve this using "git filter-branch", but since I am learning git and I want to understand the full potential of "git rebase -i", I wonder if this command can be used for such an operation.

Comment: A further alternative is the BFG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible in theory, but in practice it's usually much too painful.

The method is the same in both rebase and filter-branch.  It may help if you realize that all that an interactive rebase is, is `git cherry-pick` on steroids, as it were; and `git filter-branch` is simply an automated extra-complicated rebase across multiple branches and with merge preservation.

As usual with git, it mostly boils down to manipulating the commit graph, and adding new commits that look like existing commits but with something changed—in this case, the trees attached to those commits.  (And as soon as one commit is different, it gets a different SHA-1, which means all *subsequent* commits must change as well, to list the different SHA-1s that pop into existence as the new graph grows.)

To see how it works, start by drawing the commit graph.  You'll need a fairly complete graph depending on how far back you have to go to stop seeing the `unwanted.txt` file.  But I'll just draw a simple graph, with just one named branch, `master`:

```
I - A - B - C - F   <-- master
      \       /
        D - E
```

Here `I` is the initial commit; for simplicity let's say it does *not* have the unwanted file.  Let's say instead that this file was introduced in commit `A` and modified in `C` and `E`.

What we need to do is this:

1. Copy all of commit `I` (preserving commit author and committer, and date stamps, and so on) while removing the unwanted file, i.e., altering the source tree attached to `I` if needed.  This just gives us commit `I` back so we retain its original SHA-1.
2. Copy all of commit `A` while removing the unwanted file.  This results in a new, different commit `A'` because we change `A`'s tree to a new tree that has the file removed.  We get a new SHA-1 cryptographic checksum because the new commit is different from the old.  So we save an entry in a map that says "old commit `A` replaced by new commit `A'`.
3. Copy all of commit `B` while removing the unwanted file.  This changes the tree (remember, each commit has a complete snapshot of the entire source, so the unwanted file is in the original `B`).  Make a new commit `B'` that has the altered tree *and* has commit `A'` as its parent ID.
4. Copy all of commit `C` while removing the unwanted file, resulting in `C'`.
5. Copy all of commit `D` with our changes, resulting in `D'`.  (Note that we cannot copy `F` until we've copied all its predecessors in the graph, in this case `C` and `E`.)
6. Copy all of commit `E` with our changes.
7. Copy all of commit `F` with our changes.  The new commit `F'` has `C'` and `E'` as its two parents; we find these using the SHA-1 mapping that we've been constructing all along.
8. Last, change `master` to point to commit `F'`, abandoning the original commit `F`.

This results in a graph that looks like this:

```
    A - B - C - F    [abandoned]
   /  \       /
  /     D - E
 /
I - A' - B' - C' - F'   <-- master
       \         /
         D' - E'
```

An interactive rebase with `--preserve-merges` can handle this particular case.  If there's more than one branch, though, you have to carefully rebase the additional branches with `--onto` as needed to make use of the new commits, which you have to match up with the old commits, most likely using an SHA-1 map file that you construct manually as you go.

There's an additional wrinkle, which is that `git commit` by default refuses to make "empty" commits, where "empty" is defined as "has the same tree as the previous commit" (and is not a merge).  The filter-branch script handles this automatically for you, mapping multiple new commits to a single old commit if you choose to delete empty commits (a commit that *only* modifies the unwanted file becomes empty when the previous and new commits both give up the unwanted file).  An interactive rebase does not handle this very well when preserving merges, so that imposes even more pain.

There are some other subtle differences: for instance, when rebase "abandons" a chain of commits, they remain in the "reflog" for the branch that has been rebased, as well as in the reflog for `HEAD`.  The filter-branch script uses a different method: it copies all the references to a sub-name-space, `refs/original/`.  This all matters when you get to the point of wanting to purge the old, abandoned commits: with rebase, you "expire" old references, but with filter-branch, you forcibly remove the originals instead.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do this by editing the offending commit (that's `e` or `edit` in front of the commit in the rebase todo list,) and then just remove the file like this:

```
git rm unwanted.txt
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

This will likely give you conflicts in later commits that change the file, but that should be trivially solved by removing the file again and continue the rebase.

**Edit**:
You will most likely also have to make sure that no branches point to any commits where the unwanted file still exist, and run `git gc` to flush out unreferences blobs in the repo. This shouldn't be a problem if it a purely private repo not shared with anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

If its an entire file that you want to delete you can also do it this way :

```
rm unwanted.txt
git add unwanted.txt
git commit -m "remove unwanted file"
git rebase -i HEAD~<number_of_commit ahead>
```

and then in interactive rebase you move and fixup the "remove unwanted file" commit like this :

```
pick e33adb3 commit with unwanted file
f 095204f remove unwanted file
pick 54caa68 another commit
pick 6e03883 another commit
pick aa3d754 another commit
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. Yours is a valid approach, see also "harald"'s comment for a complementary way of doing it (cleaner IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to 'add' the file to be able to use `git rm -f` on it. That's because when performing rebasing with commit dropping, files no longer existed in the directory.

```
git add path/to/file
git rm -f path/to/file
```